# set tabcontainer active tab using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Am using the below javascript function to set active asp.net tabs. The bleow code is always return CurrentTab is "null". Any one help me to solve my issue.

```
function SetActiveTab2(tabNumber) {
            try {
                var CurrentTab = $find('<%#cust_tab.ClientID%>');
                var CurrentTab = document.getElementById('<%=cust_tab.ClientID%>');
                //Second line return the error The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

                CurrentTab.set_activeTabIndex(parseInt(tabNumber));
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message)
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this code on page's header/ Do you call `DataBind` method on it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this: `var CurrentTab = document.getElementById('<%=cust_tab.ClientID%>');` and modify previous line as this: `var CurrentTab = $find('<%= cust_tab.ClientID %>');`

Answer (score -1):

When you want to get an element by its id, you must put # of its start.

```
var CurrentTab = document.getElementById('#<%=cust_tab.ClientID%>');
```

Maybe this is the solution.

Comment: Now i got the other error CurrentTab.set_activeTabIndex is not a function

Comment: It's clear. CurrentTab is a variable not a function. You are trying to use it as a class that has set_activeTabIndex function.

Comment: JustWork Thanks its working i am using my code in form tag it's working.

Comment: It seems like you don't have a js function called "set_activeTabIndex()" but you are trying to use it. You cannot use before you declare. Once you write function set_activeTabIndex(tabNumber){ // set code goes here... } then you can use it.